# Javascript fadein fadeout to jquery fadein fade out

Tags: jquery

I have the JavaScript code to fadein.fadeout the menu, when ever user hovers it.

I want to convert JavaScript fadein fadeout to jQuery fadein fadeout.

Please help me to sort out this thing, i want jQuery because it loads in fadein fadeout style rather in a jurk in javascript

```
<style type="text/css">
     #div1 {  
         visibility: hidden;  
     }
</style>

<div onMouseOver="show('div1')" onMouseOut="hide('div1')">
    <div id="div1">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function show(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    function hide(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sinetheta/AtuDT/4/)

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">Test</div>
</div>​

$("#outer").hover(function() {
    $('#inner').fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $('#inner').fadeOut();
});​
```

Although it's generally advisable to make menus out of something a little more semantic like `<ul>`s

Comment: thanks buddy,this is the one i am looking for,my whole menu is ready with ul,just want this.

Comment: did i wrote this code correctly                               <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#outer").hover(function() {
    $('#inner').fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $('#inner').fadeOut();
});

</script>

Answer (score 0):

fade out sets display to none;

try this:

```
$("#div1").hover(
    function() {$(this).animate({opacity:1})}, // fade in
    function() {$(this).animate({opacity:1})}  // fade out
);
```

if you're into preventing jerky events from your users you might to have a look at the [hoverIntent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$("#div1").hover(
function() {$(this).show('slow')},
function() {$(this).hide('slow')}
```

);

You can use 'fast' or 'normal' param instead of 'slow'

More detail you can see [here](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

**EDIT**

if you would like tu use hand cursor when hover div, you can try this,

```
<style>#div1{cursor: pointer}</style>
```